# Does Super Mario 3D All-Stars fully emulate the GameCube analog trigger?

Tags: controllers, super-mario-sunshine, super-mario-3d-allstars

Super Mario Sunshine for the GameCube had a feature where you could control the F.L.U.D.D. water flow with the R trigger. On a hard press, Mario would stop and aim. On a soft press, Mario would keep running while shooting. But that's not all --  as I recall, the water flow could be controlled by the pressure applied. For example, on a very soft press, F.L.U.D.D. would let out a bare drizzle.

The 1.1.0 update of Super Mario 3D All-Stars supposedly added support for GameCube controllers in the Super Mario Sunshine port, including support for the analog triggers. But
it seems to me that this port still only recognizes soft press and hard press of the trigger, not the entire range of pressure in-between. When I do a very soft press, Mario doesn't stop to aim, but F.L.U.D.D. blasts at full power. I know I have the update, because I am using the inverted control scheme and the controller works as expected otherwise.

I tried searching around about this, but couldn't find any details. [TCRF](https://tcrf.net/Super_Mario_Sunshine/Version_Differences) notes only:

> Adds native GameCube controller support, replicating the control scheme from the original 2002 release. Previously, the controller simply functioned identically to the Nintendo Switch Pro Controller when used.

Is it possible to use the full analog range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the analog trigger is fully emulated, as can be seen in this video for example:

I actually just pressed the button too hard to notice. The soft flow is very subtle.